# PHP/MYSQL Inserting Multiple to textarea (Show Result)

Tags: php, mysql, textarea

i need some one to show me how to get the result of this code . 
i build a script that short links  ... i could inserting the value in sql .
but i tried to show the result of that & it didnt work >>>

Here the code  :

```
// Split the string into pieces
$pieces = explode("\n", str_replace(array("\n", "\r\n"), "\n", trim($linkfield)));

// Build the top of the INSERT query
$sql = "INSERT INTO `url`(`url`) VALUES\n";

// Build the rest of the ;INSERT query by re-assembling the
// pieces.
$sql .= "('";
$sql .= implode("'), ('", $pieces);
$sql .= "')"; 
mysql_query($sql) or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
```

its add the content to database but when its come to showing the result :

```
foreach($pieces as $d)
{

echo "$d/$ln<br />" ; 
}
```

thats work fine with getting links from database  ... the links show like this :

```
http://www.sampledomain.com/samplepost1/
http://www.sampledomain.com/samplepost2/
```

i tried this :

```
 $links = mysql_insert_id();
```

but its keep giving me the same id (one id) 
now what i need is to show ID of the links (each id with its link)

Thanks

Comment: This is not how Stackoverflow works. We all can understand what you want, but this is not the place to ask for that. Instead start with reading a book, doing some tutorials or get a trainer that is able to help you individually.

Comment: Seems variable `$pieces` contains links than why you trying to display `$rand` in textarea ?

Comment: @M8R-1jmw5r then what is it about ?  
and if you can't give help let it to someone who can ... i read alot of problems here (not different from my case) .

Comment: @Rikesh yes it is but i want to display the ids thats why i use $rand .

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
$sql .= implode("'), ('", $pieces);
```

just needs to be

```
$sql .= implode("', '", $pieces);
```

You don't need () brackets around each value

Edit:

```
mysql_insert_id()
```

should get the id of the first row inserted in the batch, all others should follow sequntially.  so in theory you can do

```
'select * from url where id > ' . mysql_insert_id();
```

to get the newly inserted links, then loop over them to put them back in the textarea

Comment: thats one mistake >>> thanks for that >
but the main problem is to get the ids of the links .
some thing like looping  the ids .

Comment: Do you want to show the code? or does that mean you got it working?

Comment: i edited the post as you can see i add foreach() and that gave me the inserted links  ... but didnt show the id of each url .